# How to show AST generated from pglast package in graphical form

Tags: python, postgresql

Below code generates AST for postgresql query

```
from pglast import parse_sql
parsed_sql = parse_sql("SELECT age FROM (select * from users group by age) as age_table WHERE age > 18;")
print(parsed_sql)
```

It gives

```
(<RawStmt stmt=<SelectStmt targetList=(<ResTarget val=<ColumnRef fields=(<String sval='age'>,)>>,) fromClause=(<RangeSubselect lateral=False subquery=<SelectStmt targetList=(<ResTarget val=<ColumnRef fields=(<A_Star>,)>>,) fromClause=(<RangeVar relname='users' inh=True relpersistence='p'>,) groupClause=(<ColumnRef fields=(<String sval='age'>,)>,) groupDistinct=False limitOption=<LimitOption.LIMIT_OPTION_DEFAULT: 0> op=<SetOperation.SETOP_NONE: 0> all=False> alias=<Alias aliasname='age_table'>>,) whereClause=<A_Expr kind=<A_Expr_Kind.AEXPR_OP: 0> name=(<String sval='>'>,) lexpr=<ColumnRef fields=(<String sval='age'>,)> rexpr=<A_Const isnull=False val=<Integer ival=18>>> groupDistinct=False limitOption=<LimitOption.LIMIT_OPTION_DEFAULT: 0> op=<SetOperation.SETOP_NONE: 0> all=False> stmt_location=0 stmt_len=78>,)
```

How can we present it into graphical form. Is there a function available which can do it?

Comment: @JonSG The links I got by searching  "python visualize ast" are to visualize ast for python language. I need  it for SQL like postgresql

Comment: Ahh so you seek a query plan visualizer rather than a python bytecode visualizer. My appologies